# First C program - Tic Tac Toe

Tags: beginner, c, tic-tac-toe

Hi I am a beginner and l would love to hear your opinion on my first C project, how can it be improved in any way, for example dynamic memory allocation isn't used in the program because I didn't quite understand where to allocate it, also I couldn't figure how to solve the problem that if input isn't an integer the program goes into an endless loop

Thanks for anyone who helps

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<ctype.h> 

void print();
void change(int num, int a);
void restart();
bool draw();
bool win();
bool check(char a[]);
bool CheckInput(int num);

char a[9] = {49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57};

void main(){ 
int b[9] = {1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1}; 
int num;
restart();
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    system("cls");
    print();
    printf("player %d enter a number option ",b[i]);
    scanf("%d",&num);
    change(num,b[i]);
    if(i == 8)
    {
    system("cls");
    print();
    }
    if(win() == true)
    {
        print();
        printf("payer %d wins",b[i]);
        return;
    }
}
printf("its a draw"); 
return;
} 

bool CheckInput(int num)
{
char (*str)[9] = &a;
if(num > 9 || num < 1)
return false;
else if(*(*str+(num-1)) == 79 || *(*str+(num-1)) == 88)
return false;
return true;
}

void change(int num, int p){
char (*str)[9] = &a;
int n = 0;
if(CheckInput(num) == true)
{
    if(p == 1)
    *(*str+(num-1)) = 88;
    else
    *(*str+(num-1)) = 79;
    return;
}
else
printf("\nincorrect enter a new number ");
scanf("%d",&n);
change(n,p);
}

void print()
{    
    printf("\n");
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
    {
        if(i == 1)
        j = 3;
        printf("  %c  |  %c  |  %c\n",a[j],a[j+1],a[j+2]);
        printf("_____|_____|_____\n");
        printf("     |     |\n");
    }
    j = 6;
        printf("  %c  |  %c  |  %c\n",a[j],a[j+1],a[j+2]);
}

void restart()
{
    char (*str)[9] = &a;
    static int j = 49;
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        *(*str + i)  = j;
        j++;
    }
    print();
}

bool win(){
char (*str)[9] = &a;
char b[3];
char c[3];
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        b[j] = *(*str + i * 3 + j);//columns
        c[j] =  *(*str + j * 3 + i);//rows
    }
    if(check(b) == true || check(c) == true)
    return true;
}
int j =0;
for(int i =0; i<3; i++)
{
    b[i] = *(*str + i * 3 + j);//left to right across 
    j++;
}
int k = 2;
for(int i =0; i < 3; i++)
{
    c[i] = *(*str + i*3 + k);//right  to left across 
    k--;
    
}
if(check(b) == true || check(c) == true)
return true;
return false;
}

bool check(char a[3]){
int count = 0;
int count2 = 0;
    for(int i =0; i<3; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] == 88)
        count++;

        else if(a[i] == 79)
        count2++;
    }
    if(count != 3 && count2 !=3)
    return false;
    return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Code Review! Here's my two cents:

#### Magic chars

Across the entire program, you use the ASCII values of chars instead of the chars themselves. This makes the code hard to read, as the reader sees a bunch of numbers at first an then has to infer what they mean, i.e. that they are actually chars.

This means, that e.g. `char a[9] = {49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57};`
should be written as `char a[9] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};`
Similarly, `88 -> 'X' and 79 -> 'O'`.

In the end, this is just a different, more legible way of writing the char codes. C will happily calculate `'9'-'7'`.

#### Inconsistent naming

`CheckInput` should be renamed to either `check_input` or `checkInput`. C doesn't have one definitive convention, but non convention I know of uses `PascalCase` for functions. Also, it's inconsistent with the rest of your functions.

#### Inexpressive names

A lot of the var names are one char wide (`a, b, i, j, ...`), making it hard to understand what they represent. It's fine for indexes used inside `for`-loops, but every other var should have a more descriptive name. For example, `a` should probably be named something like `cell_values`.

Same goes with the functions: If `print()` prints the board, why not name the function `print_board()`? Reconsider the other function names as well.

#### Indentation and formatting

Consider using an editor that has an auto-formatting feature (VSCode/VSCodium, VS, Eclipse, SublimeText, ...). As is, the formatting is very inconsistent, making the code hard to read.

#### Fun pointer things

```
// somewhere in change()

char (*str)[9] = &a;
// ...
*(*str+(num-1)) = 88;
```

Ummm... This is something to do when you want to actively confuse whoever is trying to read your code.

Since you've defined `a` outside of any function at the very top, the rest you your program can just access it as normal (read: without storing the adress in another var like `str` and dereferencing).
Hence, you should delete the first line and change the other one to `a[num-1] = 88;`. Yes, in the end the compiler will interpret this as `*(a+(num-1)) = 88;`, but indexing into an array using `[]` is easier to read than pointers. Similarly, in `win()`, `*(*str + i * 3 + j)` is the same as `a[i * 3 + j]`.

#### Comparing to boolean

`if (win() == true)` is the same as `if (win())` and for the sake of reducing visual clutter, it should be written like this. Coming back to a previous point, `win()` should have it's name chosen so that the entire line can be read as a sentence of some sort. Maybe `if (game_is_won())`? Same goes for for the use of `check()` and `CheckInput()`.

#### Printing the board

IMO in this case, printing the board with 9 `printf`s would also be fine. Also, currently the first and last row of the board are printed in two lines, while the second row is third lines tall.

#### `static`

In `restart()`, you have a line `static int j = 49;`. Making the variable `static` doesn't make much sense, since you neither need to limit it's scope across multiple files (there is only one file) nor re-use the value when the function gets called again (which it doesn't).

#### `if` without curly braces

Even if the `if` only has one line, use curly braces. I find it easier to read and it prevents bugs if you want to add or remove lines from the `if`-statement.

#### Tip regarding newlines

I find it easier to keep track of the newlines if I put them at the end of a print statement. Also, the win/draw messages should have a trailing newline, since it messes with any text that might follow (such as a command prompt).

#### Hint regarding `system("cls")`

This isn't portable. Also, the use of `system` is highly discouraged (apparently).

**As you're a beginner, don't worry about any of this**. Still, remember that some things might only work on windows and some on linux.

#### Typo

`printf("payer %s wins", b[i]);`. This should be a p**l**ayer.

Comment: Actually,  `if (win() == true)` is only the same as `if (win())` if the return is canonical boolean or `_Boolean`. Comparing against `true` is just too fragile.

Comment: Huh. I prefer to return ints, thanks for pointing that pitfall out!

Answer (score 1):

Some things to add after @mindoverflow review.

**Enable all warnings**

Save time, enable all warnings.

```
warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int' [-Wmain]
   25 | void main(){

In function 'restart':
warning: conversion from 'int' to 'char' may change value [-Wconversion]
  101 |         *(*str + i)  = j;


warning: argument 1 of type 'char[3]' with mismatched bound [-Warray-parameter=]
  139 | bool check(char a[3]){
      |            ~~~~~^~~~
note: previously declared as 'char[]'
   20 | bool check(char a[]);
      |
```

**Error checking**

Do not trust user to enter only numeric text

```
// scanf("%d",&num);
if (scanf("%d",&num) != 1) {
  Handle_input_error(); // TBD code
}
```

**Simplify**

```
//if(count != 3 && count2 != 3)
//return false;
//return true;

return count == 3 || count2 == 3;
```

**Missing comments**

Add some salient comments.

---

> how to solve the problem that if input isn't an integer the program goes into an endless loop

Avoid `scanf()`. Its error handling is very cumbersome.

Use `fgets()` to read a *line* of user input into a *string*, then process the string with `strtol(), sscanf()`, etc.

```
#define NUM_MIN 1
#define NUM_MAX 9
#define LINE_SIZE 80   // Expected max line size
char buf[2*LINE_SIZE]; // Use 2x, be generous

do {
  printf("player %d enter a number option ", b[i]);
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
    Handle_No_Input(); // Perhaps exit
  }
} while (sscanf(buf, "%d", &num) != 1 || num < NUM_MIN || num > NUM_MAX);
```

Comment: fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL  is there a way for the someone to input NULL ? what would happen if I remove the if() will it have any affect on the program ?

Comment: @BobTheCoder `NULL` is returned when there is no more input (or rare input error).  `NULL` is not an _input_.   Without the `if()`, code lacks this detection.  What would you want code to do after `fgets()` and nothing was read?

Comment: I really don't know what to do the only thing that I can think of is to use goto and exit the function or just recall the function, what would you recommend ?

Comment: @BobTheCoder For this game, I'd exit with a message about the early ending.  With a proper change to `int main()`, I'd also exit with a return code of `EXIT_FAILURE` vs. the usual `EXIT_SUCCESS`.